# Selenium python can't scrape a site

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

i need Scraping website, but display "Checking your browser before accessing" and Prevents access to the site

Do I have to define a cookie or is there another solution?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:95.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/95.0")
mainbrowser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)

mainbrowser.get('https://trade.kraken.com/charts/KRAKEN:BTC-USDT')
sleep(20)
```

Comment: I suppose you should use a chrome agent instead of firefox agent

Comment: I tried but to no avail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used the following options recently to avoid captcha detection on certain sites:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("start-maximized") 
options.add_argument("./chrome_data") # Chrome Profile data (moved from ~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome)
options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=chrome-data") 
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"]) 
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
```

Furthermore I've made use of the library selenium-stealth (https://pypi.org/project/selenium-stealth/) which has incorporated many of the techniques used to avoid detection into a package:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)    
    
stealth(
        driver,
        user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.53 Safari/537.36',
        languages = ["en-US", "en"],
        vendor = "Google Inc.",
        platform = "Win32",
        webgl_vendor = "Intel Inc.",
        renderer = "Intel Iris OpenGL Engine",
        fix_hairline = True,
        run_on_insecure_origins = True)
```